# XML-ORA-31154: invalid XML document LSX-00220: "" is wrong length, should be 1

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using PL/SQL process to validate the XML file with the XSD, but I can not validate successfully. The interesting part is that when I am trying to validate using the same "XSD" and "XML" through the others tool like Notepad++ and some online tools, the file is successfully validated but the same files are not validated through the PLSQL process. I am getting the below error

```
ORA-31154: invalid XML document
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00220: "" is wrong length, should be 1
LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "sequence", minimum is 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 354
```

```
DECLARE
    v_MyFileHandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    xmlDoc           XMLTYPE;
    xmldata          XMLTYPE;
    err_data         VARCHAR2 (2000);
    err_data         VARCHAR2 (2000);
    xmlSchema        XMLTYPE;
    schemaURL        VARCHAR2 (256)
                         := 'cts01/data/ppl/schema/SESAC_TVPP_server.xsd'; --'testcase.xsd';
    schemaPath       VARCHAR2 (256)
                         := 'cts01/data/ppl/schema/SESAC_TVPP_server.xsd';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PPL_XML_TEST
             VALUES (
                        'TEST',
                        xmltype (BFILENAME ('PPL_FILE', 'KCOY_202001.xml'),
                                 NLS_CHARSET_ID ('UTF8')));

    SELECT xml_col INTO xmldata FROM ppl_xml_test;

    xmlDoc :=
        xmldata.createSchemaBasedXML (
            'cts01/data/ppl/schema/SESAC_TVPP_server.xsd');

    IF xmlDoc.isSchemaValid () = 1
    THEN
        --dbms_output.put_line('Schema is Valid');
        NULL;
    ELSE
        xmlDoc.schemaValidate ();
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        --dbms_output.put_line ('Error: ' || SQLERRM);

        err_data := SQLERRM || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;

        INSERT INTO PPL_XML_FILE_ERROR (FILE_NAME, ERROR_LOG)
             VALUES (file_name, err_data);

        COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: these is no way to help you without seeing the xml and xsd.  can you post a [mcve] of the data?

Comment: Thanks for your attention on it, it got resolved.